# Characteristic Equation for Traceless Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

The characteristic polynomial for traceless $2\times 2, 3\times 3, 4\times 4$ matrices $A$ are

\begin{align}
x^2+&\det A \\
x^3-\frac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}A^2 x - &\det A \\
x^4-\frac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}A^2x^2-\frac{1}{3}{\rm Tr}A^3x+&\det A
\end{align}

does this pattern continue? That is, would we have

$$x^5-\frac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}A^2x^3-\frac{1}{3}{\rm Tr}A^3x^2-\frac{1}{\color{red}4}({\rm Tr}A^4+\color{red}{??} \ {\rm Tr}A^2{\rm Tr}A^2)x+\det A$$
for the characteristic polynomial for $5\times 5$ matrices. That is, do the coefficients of ${\rm Tr}A^k$ continue to be $-k^{-1}$?

Edit: it appears there is a determinant formula on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Properties) page from which this follows. I would still appreciate if anyone knows of a more elementary reason for the pattern.

Comment: I believe that from the formulas [given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Properties), it can be shown that the pattern indeed continues.

Comment: You can employ [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Application_to_the_characteristic_polynomial_of_a_matrix) to calculate these coefficients, using your favorite Computer Algebra system.